# Как заставить работать Timer?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, посмотрел статью на хабре(http://habrahabr.ru/post/136802) о создание простой игры и решил позаимствовать часть кода, связанного с Enemy, который двигается в сторону игрока. Все переписал верно, однако  враги в моем случае не появляются каждые n-секунды, а просто беспрерывно создаются и заполняют игровое поле.Как возможно сделать так, чтобы таймер работал нормально, и враги появлялись не бесперебойно, а с определенным промежутком.Вот скрин того, что вытворяется на игровом поле(Play - враг)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
public static final int WIDTH = 856;
public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
private float coordY = 480;
private MainThread thread;
private Thread thred = new Thread(this);
private Background bg;
public static Bitmap rocket;
private Bitmap rocket2;
private Paint paint;
private List<Asteroids> asteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
Bitmap ast;
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask;
Timer timer2 = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask2;

   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth() / WIDTH;
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight() / HEIGHT;
    if (canvas != null) {
        final int savedState = canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
        bg.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(rocket2, 0, coordY / 2, paint);
        Iterator<Asteroids> i = asteroids.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            Asteroids e = i.next();
            if( e.x <= 1000) {
                e.onDraw(canvas);
            } else {
                i.remove();
            }
        }
        canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
    }

}
  @Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(2000));
            asteroids.add(new Asteroids(this, ast));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
 public void update() {

    ast = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play);
    asteroids.add(new Asteroids(this, ast));

    bg.update();
}
```

Comment: А где у вас тут таймер?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я создаю его в самом начале(добавил в код)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, вот, private Thread thred = new Thread(this);

Comment: Таймер вы никак не используете, вы создали отдельный тред, который усыпляете на две секунды перед добавлянием объекта

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, а как следует изменить код, чтобы соответствовало задумке?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, ?

Answer (score 3):

Замените свой Thred и всю ту штуку в методе run() вот этим, например. Есть много причин, по которым не стоит использовать TimerTask, но пока не будем об этом. Периодичные действия можно выполнять с помощью кода ниже. Инициализируйте таймер, он начнет делать свое дело. После того как вы решили, что довольно - вызывать метод stopTimer.
Запомните пожалуйста на всю жизнь - Thread.sleep() - это ересь, которая не должна распространяться в массы, и жить в чьем то коде =))

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
. . . 
ScheduledExecutorService timer;
. . . 

private void launchTimer(){
    timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    final Random rnd = new Random();
    timer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            asteroids.add(new Asteroids(this, ast));
        }
    }, 0, rnd.nextInt(2000), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void stopTimer(){ if(timer != null) timer.shutdown(); }

// other code 

}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, я сделал так же, но откуда у нас метод shutdown()?Он у меня выделяет его красным...

Comment: отредактировал пост выше, думаю так понятно будет. Все что нужно было - вынести executor  в поле.

Comment: @Vladynyr R.timko, спасибо, ошибки больше нету)И вот еще вопросик.У меня конструктор класса Asteroids принимает GamePanel gamepanel и Bitmap bitmap, но при asteroids.add(new Asteroids(this, ast)); у меня первый параметр это Runnable и поэтому ошибка, как можно это исправить?

Comment: @En1q0d Исправте  этот перв параметр на GamePanel.this. также порекомендую вам занятся изучением синтаксиса Java, очень полезная штука

Comment: @Vladynyr R.timko,  а где следует разместить launchTimer()?В update или в draw?

Comment: @Vladynyr R.timko, просто при добавлении в updtae() проблема остается той же, только астероиды начинают мерцать(

Comment: @En1q0d Ну тут подсказать тяжело, мне неведомо _как конкретно этот код должен работать_. Попробуйте при инициализации запустить таймер, но не раньше чем инициализируете список asteroids . Эксперименты - наше все, не стоит залипать на одном месте подолгу ))